# MySql, Copy one column into another and add some text

Tags: mysql

I have a column which has an Article-ID and one empty with the picture filename. Example: The article with the ID 34.67 should get the filename 34.67.jpg and so on. There are about 20'000 articles.

[image: Screenshot]

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions that seek answers based on opinions will be closed. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for more information. You can [edit] the question so that it isn't seeking an opinion based answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your table structure or SQL dialect - it will be something like this:

```
UPDATE Tablename SET filename=concat(articleid, '.jpg')
```

Comment: You could test it in advance using `SELECT concat(articleid, '.jpg') FROM Tablename`

Comment: So I edit my question and added a screenshot. If I understnad correctly the command would be UPDATE oxarticles SET OXPIC1=concat(OXARTNUM, '.jpg') ? Correct?

Comment: So you could try `SELECT concat(OXARTNUM, '.jpg') FROM OXARTICLES` first

Comment: This would work. Can I only insert the values in columns which are empty?

Comment: then it would be something like:  `UPDATE oxarticles SET oxpic1=CONCAT(oxartnum, '.jpg') WHERE oxpic1 IS NULL`

Comment: I still have a problem with  WHERE OXPIC1 IS NULL. It selects no rows. Without it it works like a charm.

Comment: please test `WHERE oxpic1 = ''` instead

Answer (score 0):

OK, Thank you very much. I ended up using following code. This worked like a charm.

```
UPDATE oxarticles SET OXPIC1=LOWER(concat(OXARTNUM, '.jpg')) WHERE OXPIC1 = ' '
```